# How to mitigate performance problems when reviewing large pull requests on bitbucket?

Tags: c#, wcf, git, bitbucket

We are using bitbuckets for our C# projects.

In general it works great except when reviewing large pull requests. As our WCF contract is rather hefty and poorly designed whenever we make a small change to the WCF contract and import the contract into our client we get huge pull requests. These pull requests takes ages too load and the browser feels very sluggish when reviewing the code.

As we use pull requests for all commits and I am the reviewer in many cases I really suffer.

My question is; is there anyway to mitigate the performance issues for large pull requests? Any external tools? Best practices when using large WCF contracts? Tips for how to refactor the contract to make it more bitbucket friendly (I am unsure if I will be able to convince our customer to accept this though)?

PS. There's a bug for this on bitbucket but I am getting more and more desperate each day so I don't feel like waiting any longer: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/7723/improve-performance-of-large-code-reviews

Comment: try using some web accelerators like varnish (http accelerator).

Comment: Do you mean I should install a web accelerator locally to speed up the bitbucket site? That seems like something bitbucket should do on their end? In addition it seems a web accelerator would only work the second time I open pull-request otherwise it can't be cached right? I do that occassionally but most often I just review one pull request and close it.